# How to save data entered in textfields onto a database?

Tags: java, netbeans

For example:
Name:         'textfield1'
Surname:      'textfield2'
Age:          'textfield3'

Save those three textfields and make a file where it would print it like this:
textfield1, textfield2, textfield3

Comment: Need to give more info @Cedric on what it is you are trying to do e.g. platform, language, database

Comment: a little google doesn't harm; http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_enZA338ZA338&ei=XOdBS-H8H4HbjQf955GtDQ&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&ved=0CAYQBSgA&q=netbeans+web+application+example&spell=1

Answer (score 1):

your question is so vague i assume you want to learn a programming language, maybe even Java

start here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reallybigindex.html

and  here: http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/

Answer (score 1):

You did not present enough info to get a good answer but here may be the place to start:

To interact with a database in Java you use JDBC. This [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Database/JDBC20Intro/JDBC20.html) will help you understand how jdbc works.